# Cambiar o editar valor, script para hojas de google

Tags: appinventor

Tengo ese código y quiero que en en la accion añadir, en lugar de agregar una nueva fila, ponga la informacion en la misma fila del dato columna2, así como hace la busqueda de las variables, que las sustituya por lo valores nuevos, ya he intentado borrar esta linea         sheet[0].appendRow(datos); y simplemente no ha escrito nada

```
    var ssId = "1NGqFm5G942b1AwD0TD6vy42jTEf9hzqpY4ZeV9PD724";
function doGet(e){
  var accion = e.parameter.accion; 
  var columna2 = e.parameter.num; 
  var valores = e.parameter.valores; 
  var datos = buscar(accion,columna2,valores); 
  var respostaJSON = "[" + JSON.stringify(datos) + "]";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(respostaJSON).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);  
}
function buscar(accion,columna2,valores){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId) ;
  var sheet = sh.getSheets();
  if(accion=="contar"){
    var columna2 = sheet[0].getDataRange().getNumRows()-1;
var resultado = {"accion": "contar", "columna2" : columna2};
    return resultado;
  };
if(accion=="anadir"){
    var datos = valores.split(',') ; 
    sheet[0].appendRow(datos);
    return {"accion" : accion,"valores" : datos };  
  }else{
    var datos = sheet[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i in datos){
      var row = datos[i]; 
      var num = row[1] ;  
      if (num == columna2){
        var num = row[1] ;  
        var columna2 = row[0] ;  
        var columna3 = row[2] ;  
        var columna4 = row[3] ;
        var columna5 = row[4] ; 
        var columna6 = row[5] ; 
        var columna7 = row[6] ;
        var columna8 = row[7] ;
        var columna9 = row[8] ;
        var columna10 = row[9] ;
        if(accion=="consultar"){
var resultado = {"accion": "consultar", "num" : num , "columna2" : columna2, "columna3" : columna3 , "columna4" : columna4 , "columna5" : columna5 , "columna6" : columna6 , "columna7" : columna7 , "columna8" : columna8 , "columna9" : columna9 , "columna10" : columna10 };
        };      
        if(accion=="eliminar"){{
          var fila =  parseInt(i)+1 ; 
          sheet[0].setValue(fila);   
var resultado = {"valor" : fila , "accion" : "eliminar", "num" : num , "columna2" : columna2, "columna3" : columna3 , "columna4" : columna4 , "columna5" : columna5 , "columna6" : columna6 , "columna7" : columna7 , "columna8" : columna8 , "columna9" : columna9 , "columna10" : columna10 };
        };   
        return resultado; 
     
   };
           }; 
         };
       };
     };
```